# Firebase Internal Error Occurred [Bad Request] - Email Auth

Tags: authentication, firebase

I continue to receive an error when using createUserWithEmailAndPassword or signInWithEmailAndPassword. Both throw "An internal error has occurred. [ Bad Request ]" error and I can't figure out why. All of my API and SHA1 keys between Google API and Firebase API match and I have email/password authentication enabled. Here's a snippet of my code, but I can't figure out why this happens.

public void signIn(String email, String password) {

```
mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
          @Override
          public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
              //On successful sign in...

              //Take the user to MainActivity
              Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class);
              startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
              dialogFragment.dismissAllowingStateLoss();

            } else {
              //If user can't sign in, Toast, hide progress bar, un-dim background, and make screen touchable again
              Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Invalid username or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              dialogFragment.dismissAllowingStateLoss();
              getActivity().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
            }
          }
        });
}
```